# Is foreign key reference stored at django level or MySQLDB

Tags: python, mysql, django

Consider that there is a mysql table created as

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and `table2` defined as

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `table1_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

by running migrations from the models.

Here table 2 references 1 and this relationship is mentioned in models. Now when I query these tables in MySQL I do not see anything like references from table2 to 1.

I would like to know is it the responsibility of the django to store such relationships. If so then in case I have to change my ORM from django to something else how do I manage to migrate such relationships.

Also if I look at it as an "ORM is just a wrapper to ensure that such relationships should be adhered" then why not create such relationships during table creation via migrations. Which means ensuring that reference becomes part of the table definition. So tomorrow if I choose to use another ORM all i need to do is import table definitions.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Seems like django does ensure that such relationships are made part of the table definition. I was looking at the wrong place. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

The ORM is just a higher level way of working with the database, its schema, and retrieving its data. It doesn't store anything, it just provides you a way of working with the data below as defined in the schema.

You can see in the schema you've shown here that table2 has a `table1_id`.

The very first line in the documentation for [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#module-django.db.migrations):

> Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into your database schema.

So however you get there, at the end of it, you're left with a database schema that has nothing at all to do with Django.

Comment: If I agree to the fact that ORM is just a wrapper to ensure that such relationships should be adhered then why not create such relationships during table creation via migrations.

Comment: @techsavvy - You mean like creating a `table1_id` field in the db schema?

Comment: Hey @Sayse thanks for answering this question I have updated the question. These tables are created by running migrations in the models.

Answer (score 0):

How are they supposed to be related? Table1_id looks like the reference to the other table.

How should table1_id be populated? If it is all manual entry, then there should be no problem.